# Project architecture using Nuxt/Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, nuxt.js

I'm setting up a new project for my job, and I'd like some advice if possible. My project consist of using nuxt.js for frontend and firebase for backend. So it's basically 100% frontend project.

My website will have two big features :
1. The frontend side of thing: home page, search page, view profiles, etc.
2. The backend side of thing: a dashboard where the user can register and manage whatever data he will have to enter, edit, delete, etc.

So considering this project will become fairly big in the near future, and performance is a huge priority for this project,

My question is:

Would it be better to have two sub-project with different dependencies (node_modules and package-lock, etc) and also different nuxt.config.js. The subfolder for the dashboard would be in a sub-domain, example: www.dashboard.website.com, And for the frontend side would just be the main domain www.website.com.

OR

Just put everything in one big project and share the dependencies even if some won't be needed in the dashboard and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't something that can be so quickly answered.

Consider some things.

Hosting - I assume you already have these domains if not i suggest snatching them up along with their counterparts .org, .com, .info (Idk how big your company is but they should have resources for this)

Server - If you do not house your own, you will have to depend on a reliable provider with great up time and speed.

Data - Design a data structure for every metric you will be housing and think in terms of how you can possibly add more you aren't thinking of. Determine the types, location, callbacks, descriptions, etc. (I advise heavy documentation/excel file of each metric you create)

Security - Depending on what your hosting on your servers - if they are yours, you have to be in compliance with all laws and regulations. If your hosting eu data you will have more regulations. I would ask your IT department if they require an audit etc before hand.

Storage - What types of files, data will you be processing in forms of all request types and how they will affect your front end/backend.

That's now answering the direct question but if you plan better based off your original question you wont be stuck recreating the first month over and over because of complications,

Comment: All the hosting will be through Firebase cloud storage directly (Firestore).

The data will be managed there, and the website will also be deployed through firebase as well. For security, that's a good idea thank you !

I'll base my structure around all those things and make sure to think about everything so just like you said, I don't have to re-do it again. Great insight thanks a lot